# about necessary and sufficient condition, again

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Here I have a sentence picked up from a first year book:

> The statement “if A then B” is equivalent to the statement “A is a sufficient condition for B” and to the statement “B is a necessary condition for A"

I understand the first part, but I cannot see how the statement “if A then B”
leads to the conclusion that “B is a necessary condition for A".

Is a sufficient condition always a necessary condition?

Hope anyone could help for some explanation and examples.

Thanks

Comment: Another way you could put it: $B$ follows necessarily from $A$. For if $A$ is true, $B$ is true necessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is a sufficient condition always a necessary condition?

The phrases do not apply *to A and B directly*, they are just two ways of describing the same **relationship** between A and B while emphasizing the role of one of the conditions in the implication. The phrase "A is a necessary/sufficient condition" has no meaning without reference to a second condition.

As for an example, being a square is a sufficiently strong condition to guarantee being a rectangle. On the other hand, it is absolutely necessary to be a rectangle if you have any hope of being a square.

This might help: "being a rectangle is necessary for being a square: if you're not a rectangle, you are not a square." This statement just says "not rectangle $\implies$ not square" which is just the contrapositive of "square $\implies$ rectangle."

Comment: So, the answer of this part of my question is. No, not always. ? But a sufficient condition could also be a necessary condition. Please correct me.

Comment: @math101 oh sure: it is possibl, for A to be both necessary and sufficient for B, that is a biconditional. But it's not the case in general.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand the first part, but I cannot see how the statement “if A then B” leads to the conclusion that “B is a necessary condition for A".

You can get this intuition by drawing a truth table for $A \rightarrow B$

$$\begin{array} {|c|}
\hline
A & B & A \to B \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1\\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0\\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

You will see that whenever $A$ is true, so is $B$, which essentially mirrors the intuitive idea of $B$ being necessary for $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my understanding:

It means that $A$ necessarily entails $B$.

The first statement tells you that it's enough to have $A$ to get $B$. But you *could* have $B$ without $A$.

The second statement tells you that given $A$, you *have* to have $B$.

Answer (score 0):

"A is sufficient for B" is $A\to B$.  Also stated as "If A then B".

This means that the truth of A garantees the truth of B, although B *might* be true when A is not.

That is either A is false or B is true.

---

"B is necessary for A" is $B\leftarrow A$.

This means that A cannot be true when B is not, but that A *may* not be true when B is.

That is either A is false or B is true.

---

Ergo they are equivalent.  $$A\to B \quad\iff\quad B\leftarrow A$$